# Casting an interface

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have the following code

```
  var distributionUnits = _distributionUnitRepository.FindByCompanyId(userSession.CompanyId);
```

This returns 2 records. However when i tried the following cast. I have no records.

```
        var myentities = distributionUnits as List<IEntity>;
```

Is this kind of cast possible?

Further info.

```
 public interface IEntity
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }



public class DistributionUnit : IEntity
{

   public virtual string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You forgot the further info that would actually help: what is the signature of FindByCompanyId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myentities = distributionUnits.Cast<IEntity>().ToList();
```

assuming your distributionUnits are either IEntity or something that either inherits or implements IEntity.

Comment: it was not me but i think reason is that you wrote code without actually knowing type of distributionUnits, this is just guessing

Answer (score 2):

> This returns 2 records. However when i tried the following cast. I have no records.

```
var myentities = distributionUnits as List<IEntity>;
```

> Is this kind of cast possible?

Well, you haven't told us the return type of `DistributionUnitRepository.FindByCompanyId`, but probably not. You see, let's say the return type is `List<DistributionUnit>`. If you could make that cast, the following would be possible:

```
class EvilEntity : IEntity { }

myentities.Add(new EvilEntity());
```

and now you've just added an instance of `EvilEntity` to your list `List<DistributionUnit>` which is clearly absurd.

Further, if the return type of `DistributionUnitRepository.FindByCompanyId` is not even a `List<DistributionUnit>`, but say, `IEnumerable<DistributionUnit>` that is just `yield`ed, then of course the cast is impossible.

You probably want to say

```
var myentitites = distributionUnits.Cast<IEntity>().ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for comments, think yurif got the cast first. but also correct +1

Comment: @frosty: Note that you asked a question as to whether or not the cast you specified was possible, and selected an answer that didn't even address that question but just gave you a workaround.